# Pygal hide a particular legend

Tags: python-2.7, pygal

Is there a way to hide a particular legend in pygal graph. I did go through their docs and it says nothing about displaying it partially.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to hide the legend of the graph by using their configurations part when declaring the Pygal variable.

[Legend Highlight](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/legend.html?highlight=legend) will be useful in changing the way in which a legend is displayed.